# jqgrid display editform (the entire form) based on dataURL result

Tags: forms, jqgrid, edit

I am using form editing but I only want the ADD form to appear if the results from dataURL are correct. I can hide it, but I really don't want it at all on condition. Plus, the hide() only works after the alert is cleared

```
$("#schedule").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
    url: './ar_schedule_update.cgi?',
    editData: {visitor:visitor},
    beforeInitData: function() {
        $('#schedule').setColProp('archiveid',{editable: true,hidden:false, edittype: 'select', 
            editoptions: {dataUrl: './ar_archiveid_edit_options.cgi?system=' + selected_system,
                          buildSelect: function(data) {
                                if (data.match(/^ERROR/)) {
                                       $('#editmodschedule').hide(); //Makes it disappear ok after alert cleared
                                       alert(data);
                                       return false;
                                }
                                return data;
                           }
                    }
            });
       },
       beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
             //NEED TO EVALUATE CONDITION HERE? AND BAIL IF ERROR
       },
       onClose: function() {...............
```

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: "if the results from dataURL are correct." ? Please explain this out a bit more.

Comment: I use dataURL to build a select. If the results of dataURL (which are extracted from a database) are empty, or not what the user can use (but mostly empty) I dont even want to present the form. If I do present the form with or without all the form elements, I'm wasting my user's time if they submit, only to have the server report errors.

Comment: The form is an ADD form. I allow the user to filter the grid. The ADD in conjunction with the filter is supposed to provide a select specific to the filter, which it does (the 'selected_system' variable is postdata from a filter)